# $\overline{A \cup B}$ is read as "neither $A$ nor $B$", how about $\overline{A \cap B}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$\overline{A \cup B}$ is read as "neither $A$ nor $B$", how about $\overline{A \cap B}$?

I know that $\overline{A \cap B}$ equals to $\overline{A}\cup \overline{B}$ which can be read as "not A or not B". But it is not what I am looking for.

Comment: is overline here complement? I want to say the answer you are looking for is "either in $A$ or in $B$"? Break it down, first the element is in $A$ and in $B$, then the complement of this which is one or the other right? Because if you are not in both you're in one or the other, draw Venn diagram for this.

Comment: At least to me, "neither $A$ nor $B$" seems the most appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Neither or only one of A and B
2. At most one of A and B
3. Not both A and B
4. ‘NAND’ A and B  (borrowing the terminology of logic gates)

Comment: All of which can be summarized as "not both A and B".

Answer (score 1):

I'd say "not both A and B"

Comment: same as in $A$ or in $B$ right?

Comment: @HossienSahebjame Different:  “in A or in B” is typically understood to mean $A\cup B$ (inclusive “or”), whereas the OP's given set expression allows for elements that are in neither A nor B.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that can cause trouble in understanding set theory (or algebra of sets) is not to distnguish rigorously enough sets (or set expressions) and propostions.

Set expressions are just symbols, they are not true or false (though they have a denotation, a reference). Propositions are true or false; they have meaning or sense.

The proposition $\neg (A\lor B)$ is read " it is not the case that (A is true or B is true)". (Note that , here, A and B are propositions themselves, not sets).

But the correspondng set expression is read " the complement of the union of set A and set B". That is: " the set of all x such that it is not the case that (x belongs to set A or x belongs to set B)". So, we use the NOR (logical) operator to define the complement of  a $\cup$ - set.

The set expression you are trying to read is " the complement of the intersection of set A and of set B".

Comment: While I vehemently agree with you—and I issue the same reminder frequently myself—that expressions (e.g., $A\cup B,\;x^2+7$) ought to be distinguished from statements/equations (which have truth values), I don't think that reading $A\cup B$ as “(set) A or (set) B” is amiss or at odds with that.  (Similarly, both “the probability of the occurrence of **A and B**” and “the probability of the occurrence of **A intersection B**” are equivalent informal readings of $P(A\cap B),$ and neither reading is treating $A\cap B$ as a statement at all.)